# The value retrieved has a null value. How to eliminate them?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I already succeed in retrieving the RGB pixel value from compareHexaRGB method. And the output doesn't seem convincing as the output includes with a null character too. How can I eliminate them?

Second, when I tried to combine String[][] char 1 + char 2 I get an error stated that it is bad operand for type "+". But I would like to combine the 2 string in order for me to be able to convert it to ASCII character.

Here is the code for compareHexaRGB method:

```
public class compareHexaRGB
{
 private static int w;
 private static int h;
 private static BufferedImage img;
 private static BufferedImage img2;
 private static String[][] check_hex2;
 private static String[][] check_hex4;
 private static String[][] message;

 public static void compareHexaRGB(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage image2, int width, int height) throws IOException
{
w = width;
h = height;
img = image;
img2 = image2;

}

public void check() throws IOException
{
    getPixelRGB1 pixel = new getPixelRGB1();
    getPixelData1 newPD = new getPixelData1();

    int[] rgb;
    int count = 0;

    int[][] pixelData = new int[w * h][3];
    check_hex2 = new String[w][h];
    check_hex4 = new String[w][h];

    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            rgb = newPD.getPixelData(img, i, j);

            for(int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++)
            {
                pixelData[count][k] = rgb[k];
            }

                if(pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 2 are the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]);
                }
                if(pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 4 are the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);
                }
                if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 2 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]);
                    check_hex2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j];
                    System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 2: " + check_hex2[i][j]);
                }
                if(!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 4 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);
                    check_hex4[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j];
                    System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 4: " + check_hex4[i][j]);
                }
                if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]) || (!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j])))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nOne of the pixel values at position 2 and 4 are not the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j] + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]);

                    if(!pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]) || (pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j])))
                    {
                        check_hex2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j];
                        System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 2: " + check_hex2[i][j]);
                    }

                    if(!pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j]) || (pixel.display_imgHex4()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j])))
                    {
                        check_hex4[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex4()[i][j];
                        System.out.println("\nOutput Hex 4: " + check_hex4[i][j]);
                    }

                }
            count++;
            System.out.println("\nOutput Count: " + count);
        }

    }

}

public String[][] getCheck_hex2()
{
    return check_hex2;
}

public String[][] getCheck_hex4()
{
    return check_hex4;
}
}
```

Code for extractMessage method:

```
public class extractMessage
{
private static String character;
private static String[][] char1;
private static String[][] char2;
private static int w;
private static int h;
private static String[][] in;

public static void extractMessage(int width, int height, String[][] inn)
{
    character = "";
    w = width;
    h = height;
    in = inn;
}

public static void printString2DArray(String[][] inn) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inn.length; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < inn[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (i != 0 && j == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(inn[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public static void charExtract()
{
    compareHexaRGB hexRGB = new compareHexaRGB();

    char1 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex2();
    char2 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex4();
    String[][] combine = char1 + char2;

    System.out.println("Char 1: ");
    printString2DArray(char1);
    System.out.println("Char 2: ");
    printString2DArray(char2);

}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Char 1: 
null
null
null
null
null
null
 null
null
6
6
null
null
 6
null
null
null
null
null
Char 2: 
null
null
null
null
null
null
 null
null
2
3
null
null
 1
null
null
null
null
null
```

Any suggestion or correction I would highly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are getting lots of nulls as the pixels at these positions are the same. In your `check()` method, when the pixels are the same you do not add anything to the array at that position - so it remains null. Add a place holding character at these points like `-` or something.
- Your print method is printing each element on a line also, it would be more readable if you printed the 2D array like a matrix. You can do this by modifying your method to this

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < inn.length; i++) 
  {
      for(int j = 0; j < inn[i].length; j++)
      {
         System.out.print(inn[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
  ```

  Another helpfull method you might be interested in is [`Arrays.deepToString(Array)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object%3aA-), but this creates a single string and would require manipulation to print on multiple lines would be easier to do the following

  ```
  for(String[] arr : inn)
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
  ```
- You get the error when trying to add the arrays as you simply cannot do that - add two arrays together without looping the contents. You will need a loop similar to above

  ```
  char1 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex2();
  char2 = hexRGB.getCheck_hex4();
  //assuming char1 and char2 are the same size and symmetrical
  String[][] combine = new String[char1.length][char1[0].length]

  for (int i = 0; i < char1.length; i++) 
  {
      for(int j = 0; j < char1[i].length; j++)
      {
           // This will only concatenate the strings though,
           // If you want the numerical addition you will have to 
           // convert them to ints first
           combine[i][j] = char1[i][j] + char2[i][j];
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: in your 1st suggestion, you stated that I should add a place to hold the character. can i do something like this --> if(pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j].equals(pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]))
                        {
                            System.out.println("\nPixel values at position 2 are the same." + "\n" + pixel.display_imgHex2()[i][j] + "  " + pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j]);
                            not_stega2[i][j] = pixel.display_img2Hex2()[i][j];
                        } ? or am i doing it wrong?